# Unable to import modules in node-worker-thread-pool

Tags: javascript, typescript, node-modules, worker-thread, node-worker-threads

I am using node-worker-thread-pool package.I am unable to import certain node modules into my worker.ts, giving an error SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module. How to resolve this. Is there any other package which can help, since my task for worker thread have other import/module dependency?

```
import {Item} from "@package in node modules";
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at MessagePort.<anonymous> (node:internal/main/worker_thread:187:24)
    at MessagePort.[nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:562:20)
    at MessagePort.exports.emitMessage (node:internal/per_context/messageport:23:28)
Emitted 'error' event on PoolWorker instance at:
    at PoolWorker.[kOnErrorMessage] (node:internal/worker:289:10)
    at PoolWorker.[kOnMessage] (node:internal/worker:300:37)
    at MessagePort.<anonymous> (node:internal/worker:201:57)
    at MessagePort.[nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:562:20)
    at MessagePort.exports.emitMessage (node:internal/per_context/messageport:23:28)
    at PoolWorker.[kOnExit] (node:internal/worker:267:5)
    at Worker.<computed>.onexit (node:internal/worker:198:20)
```